# How to do calculations on regex parts in a replaceAll before replacing?

Tags: java, regex, format

I have a string like: `"2E6 3.34e-5 3 4.6"` and I want to use replaceAll to replace tokens like:

`"((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)(E|e)((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)"`

(i.e. two numbers with e or E between them) into the equivalent normal number format (i.e. replace `"2E6"` with `"2000000"` and `"3.34e-5"` with `"0.0000334"`)

I wrote:

```
value.replaceAll("((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)(E|e)((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)", "($1)*10^($6)");
```

but I would like to actually multiply the 1st argument by 10 to the power of the 2nd argument, not just writing it that way .. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I did the following based on your suggesions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)(E|e)((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("2E6 3.34e-5 3 4.6");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "WHAT HERE??"); // What HERE ??
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, this is what I reached:

```
// 32 #'s because this is the highest precision I need in my application
private static NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.################################");

private static String fix(String values) {
    String[] values_array = values.split(" ");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(String value:values_array){
        try{
            result.append(formatter.format(new Double(value))).append(" ");
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){ //If not a valid double, copy it as is
            result.append(value).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return result.toString().substring(0, result.toString().length()-1);
}
```

Comment: I think that a regex is not the best solution. Why do you need this done with regexes?? I think a workaround like the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666935/implemention-of-eval-in-java would be better.

Comment: This is not what I want. If so, I'd easily split it using spaces, and for each string just do `new Double(my_string_value)`, but the problem is that the scientific notation (with e or E) is already accepted by Java, that's why wrapping into a Double Object doesn't help.

Comment: Of course, I was just curious about why you need to do this with regexes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert scientific number notation into normal formal you can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();

    double num1 = 2E6;
    formatter = new DecimalFormat("##########");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(num1)); 

    double num2 = 3.3e-5;
    formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(num2));
}
```

Just add the logic to split the intial string over `spaces` and apply the above logic.

You can check more about the symbols like `#`(in this case) at the javadoc for [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
Symbol Location     Localized?  Meaning   
------------------------------------------------------------
#      Number       Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Comment: It seems like the solution, but let me ask you, why exactly 10 hashes? What would happen if I make them 5 or 20 hashes??

Answer (score 2):

```
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)(E|e)((\\-)?[0-9]+(\\.([0-9])+)?)");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher( "2E6 3.34e-5 3 4.6");
    while (matcher.find()) {

      String a = matcher.group(1); //The $1
      String b = matcher.group(6); //The $6
      String repl = null;
      if( a != null && b != null ) { //Check if both exist for this match
                      //Parse, do calculations and convert to string again
          repl = BigDecimal.valueOf( Double.parseDouble( a ) * Math.pow( 10, Double.parseDouble( b ) )).toString();
      }
      else {
          repl = matcher.group(0); //Else return unaffected
      }
      matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, repl);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buffer);

    System.out.println( buffer.toString());
     //"2000000.0 0.0000334 3 4.6"
```

Comment: Your solution works great, but for long numbers it fails (for example `2e10` gives `2.0E+10`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do that with replaceAll method. You seem to know regex so I'll only point you in the right direction. Try the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class. With this, you can compile a regex pattern and find groups, and for example multiply the first group with 10 to the power of the group after e.

Comment: Can you provide a small example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything more complicated than copying groups verbatim from the match to the replacement then you'll have to do it longhand using the `find()` and `appendReplacement/appendTail` methods of `Matcher`.  There's a good example in the [javadoc for `appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29).

Inside the loop you can use `m.group()` to access the matched string, and `m.group(n)` to access the n'th parenthesis group, so you could create a suitable `NumberFormat` for the output format you need and then do something like

```
double val = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
m.appendReplacement(nf.format(val));
```

Or using `String.format`

```
m.appendReplacement(String.format("%f", val));
```

(or use `BigDecimal` if you can't be sure your values will all be representable as `double`).