# Why my code is giving NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, android

I have code like this :

```
int [] arrayOfImages = new int[namesOfSubjectsColorCode.size()];
    int y = 0;    
        for (int x = 0 ; x<namesOfSubjectsColorCode.size();x++) {
            nameOfColorCode = namesOfSubjectsColorCode.get(x);
            String str = "com" + "." + "nyurals" + "." + "R" + "." + "drawable" + "." + nameOfColorCode;
            arrayOfImages[y] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            // Integer.parseInt(str);
            y++;
        }
```

Here, I have created integer array. Then, I have created string and by using `Integer.parseInt()` I want to convert it to int so that, my array of integer should generate dynamically.  It is giving `NumberFormatException`.

Please suggest to me a solution for this.

Comment: Because "com.nyurals.R.drawable.." is not an Integer.

Comment: You're expecting it to look up that resource... that's not going to happen.

Comment: can you suggest any solution.. beacause, I have color code for 10 subjects coming from Webservices  and I have to map this to R.drawable image of resource folder.. please suggest dear friend...

Comment: use eval() function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666935/implemention-of-eval-in-java

Comment: Maybe you need to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name

Comment: use eval() function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666935/implemention-of-eval-in-java

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Answer (score 1):

Argument for Integer.parseInt() is invalid, you can't pass it string like "com.nyurals.." etc

From the docs:

```
public static int parseInt(String s)
                throws NumberFormatException
```

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

And that's exactly what you're getting: NumberFormatException.

**EDIT:**

You probably want to do something like this:

```
nameOfColorCode = namesOfSubjectsColorCode.get(x);
String str = "" + nameOfColorCode;

int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(str, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

arrayOfImages[y] = resourceId;
y++;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for this `String` to be reasonably turned into an `int`.

```
    String str = "com" + "." + "nyurals" + "." + "R" + "." + "drawable" + "." + nameOfColorCode;
```

Something like this would be expected:

```
String str = "1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Its obvious that it gives you NumberFormatException. Look at your code :

Your `str` variable contains `String` which cant parse into Integer value.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt()` expects to be given an integer of some sort, not a string of the format `com.nyurals.R.drawable.<<nameOfColorCode>>`.

Generally, in Android, you would access the variables directly with something like:

```
R.drawable.SomeName
```

rather than trying to decode (or, in your case, directly using) the string to get a value.

For example, the following code gets the surface view based on an ID:

```
SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.PfrRightAntiView);
```

If you *do* need to dynamically extract a resource based on a string known only at runtime, look into [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), an example of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488238/using-android-getidentifier).

As per [this article](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html), that method may not be the fastest. It may be better to use the reflection method as shown in that link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the int (id) of a resource than you should use

```
Resources res = activity.getResources();
res.getIdentifier("name","resourceType",activty.getPackageName());
```

change the **name** with actual name and **resourceType** with actual resource type (drawable,color,etc);
As others wrote you don't have an int in your string, it's just an int and not a reference to resoruce

Answer (score 0):

You can access the constants you're trying to reference via http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/ but you really don't want to do that.

You'd be better served putting the int's in some form of map of which you can then select some kind of subset dependent on changing information

Answer (score 0):

May your str returns null so Integer.parseInt(null) return number format exception